# Salesforce have standard Open hours For Stores?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

I do some researh and cant find anything,

exist something like this?
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not so obviously on one screen (though you could build something), but they are [Business Hours](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_supporthours.htm&type=5) and [Holidays](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizesupport_holidays.htm&type=5). Salesforce provides the ability to calculate times based on these support hours (e.g. "SLA is 20 business hours, when does that elapse given store hours?"), and can be used in Apex as well to support custom code that leverages this information.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Business Hours](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_supporthours_guidelines.htm). That's probably something you need.

You can find them in Setup -> Business Hours.